# Compilation error when trying to find_if an unique_ptr in a vector

Tags: c++, gcc, unique-ptr

This code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Foo
{
    int bar;

    Foo(const int val) :
        bar(val)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>(42));
    Foo* ptr = vec.back().get();
    auto& it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<Foo>& p)
    {
        return p.get() == ptr;
    });
    if (it != vec.end())
    {
        vec.erase(it);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Works fine in MSVC, but errors out in GCC 5.1:

> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> prog.cpp:19:25: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >&' from an rvalue of type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >'
>     auto& it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr& p)

1. Which compiler is bugged?
2. How do I erase a pointer from a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr` correctly?

Comment: "bugged" implies it's unintentional behavior. It's not. The MSVC devs are well aware of this and have no intention of ever changing it.

Comment: However, if you want to enforce strict standards compliance (to the best of the compiler's current ability), use the [`/Za` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gcc is correct here. You can't initialize a lvalue reference with an rvalue, and you're doing it for the `it` reference to an iterator ([`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an rvalue)

```
auto& it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<Foo>& p)
    ^
```

Either make it an object:

```
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<Foo>& p)
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GXSfdN6rf5V8f1dS)

or a const reference:

```
auto const& it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<Foo>& p)
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UupheMXf9zHqT07l)

Other than that, your code for erasing an element from a vector is correct

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 will emit a warning that a nonstandard extension is being used if you turn on level 4 warnings `/W4`:

```
warning C4239: nonstandard extension used:
note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
```

---

```
#pragma warning( push, 3 )  
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#pragma warning( pop ) 
#pragma warning( disable : 4710 )

struct Foo
{
    int bar;

    Foo(const int val) :
        bar(val)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>(42));
    Foo* ptr = vec.back().get();
    auto& it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<Foo>& p)
    {
        return p.get() == ptr;
    });
    if(it != vec.end())
    {
        vec.erase(it);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
1>c:\users\flatmouse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project79\project79\source.cpp(25): warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'initializing': conversion from 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\flatmouse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project79\project79\source.cpp(25): note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
```